# Globalization does not work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem with globalization in ASP.NET Web API. It returns the correct localized string in the first request. But subsequent requests with different `Accept-Language` always return the same localized string as the first request.

I have inspected `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and they are correct. But the loaded resources is not the same as a thread culture.

It looks like there is some cache. But I have no idea where is it.